# Albert hotkey (shortcut) didn't work in Gnome Terminal or Gnome Terminator

Tags: command-line, gnome, shortcut-keys, 20.10

I'm on Ubuntu 20.10 with Gnome Wayland session.

I have installed [Albert](https://albertlauncher.github.io/) (version `0.17.2`) and I have setup `Ctrl+Alt+Space` Albert hotkey.

In Gnome Tweaks, I have enabled « Ctrl position - Swap Left Win with Left Ctrl » option.

This hotkey works perfectly when I'm in Firefox, VSCode, Signal, Mattermost, xterm... windows.

Issue: I can't open Albert when I'm in Gnome Terminal or [Gnome Terminator](https://gnometerminator.blogspot.com) windows.

How can I fix that?

Best regards,
Stéphane

---

Same question on:

- [`albertlauncher/albert` GitHub issue](https://github.com/albertlauncher/albert/issues/1006)
- [`gnome-terminator/terminator` GitHub issue](https://github.com/gnome-terminator/terminator/issues/407)
- [`GNOME/gnome-terminal` Gnome GitLab issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-terminal/-/issues/337)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is Wayland. Wayland does not support Xlib keygrabs.  Without xlib installed Albert would even crash. However if it is installed it results in this weird behavior. If an X window is focused the hotkey works, if not it doesnt.

Wayland does not allow keygrabs by design.

Thus, set up your own custom shortcut key in your desktop environment (compositor in Wayland terms) instead. Specify `albert toggle` as the command to run. For example in Gnome Shell, head to "Settings" - "Keyboard" and define a custom shortcut there that triggers the command.

Comment: « Let your desktop environment (compositor in Wayland terms) handle the hotkey and run albert toggle » how can I setup that?

Comment: Launch « gnome-control-center », go to « Keyboard Shortcuts », at bottom page, click on « + », fill "albert toggle" in command and configure your shortcut.

Comment: @harobed's solution fixed my issue on ubuntu 22.04LTS.